# htaccess redirect specific TLD to subfolder while preserving existing root-to-subfolder redirect

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a domain `example.com` which hosts an English version of a website on `example.com/en-US/` and a French version on `example.com/fr-FR/`

Until now we have used the English version as default, so we would redirect everybody requesting `example.com` to `example.com/en-US/` using these rules in the `.htaccess` file:

```
Redirect 301 /index.html http://examle.com/en/

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

So when you request http://exmaple.com in your browser, the server will request the index.html and that will trigger the Rediret to the `/en-US/` directory.

Now we got the French `example.fr` TLD - pointing to the same webspace. I am now looking for a way to reirect the browser request http://example.fr to http://example.com/fr-FR/

I have tried adding the following condition, but it results in some kind of loop adding lots of `/en-US/`s into the URL.

Please help me, I need a way to redirect

> hxxp://example.com --> hxxp://example.com/en-US/
>
> hxxp://example.fr --> hxxp://example.com/fr-FR/
>
> and all people explicitly requesting hxxp://example.com/index.html --> hxxp://example.com/en-US/ too

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule based on condition based on `HTTP_HOST`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:index\.html)?$ /en-US/ [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:index\.html)?$ /fr-FR/ [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L,NE]
```